# SQL Possible Inner Join on itself

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has a few different types of transactions

I'm displaying only 2 of them in the table below 'Submission' and 'EligibilityCheck'

I need to write a query that will only show the Submission transaction **IF** the 'EligibilityCheck' transaction of the same Session has 'Yes' for 'IsEligible'

```
TABLEA
Transaction         Session     IsEligible
Submission          12345678
EligibilityCheck    12345678    Yes
EligibilityCheck    12345678    Yes
EligibilityCheck    12345678    Yes
EligibilityCheck    22222222    Yes
EligibilityCheck    33333333    No
Submission          87654321
EligibilityCheck    87654321    No
EligibilityCheck    87654321    No
Submission          77777777
EligibilityCheck    77777777    Yes
Submission          11111111
EligibilityCheck    11111111    No
```

This is what the query results should look like

```
TABLEB
Transaction     Session     IsEligible
Submission      12345678
Submission      77777777
```

I've tried to do it with an `Inner Join` but I'm not sure if you can `Inner Join` on itself? I also tried to do it as a nested query but it doesn't bring it all up.

Any ideas? I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Comment: Google how to use CTEs. I think this is the easiest way - put your IF condition into the CTE and then join to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a self-join using the `Session` column and only selecting rows where `IsEligible = 'Yes'`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A1.*
FROM TABLEA A1
JOIN TABLEA A2 ON A2.Session = A1.Session AND A2.IsEligible = 'Yes'
WHERE A1.[Transaction] = 'Submission'
```

Alternatively you can use an `EXISTS` subquery:

```
SELECT A1.*
FROM TABLEA A1
WHERE [Transaction] = 'Submission' 
  AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM TABLEA A2
              WHERE A2.Session = A1.Session
                AND A2.IsEligible = 'Yes')
```

Output:

```
Transaction     Session     IsEligible
Submission      12345678    
Submission      77777777
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=8410965836a9062524ccdd0a960723b9)

Note I've assumed that `IsEligible` will only be `'Yes'` when `Transaction` is `'EligibilityCheck'`. If that is not the case, you would need to add

```
A2.[Transaction] = 'EligibilityCheck'
```

to the `JOIN/EXISTS` conditions.